# Swipe big working what next?

Tags: iphone, touchscreen

My iPhone 4s will not let me swipe to unlock, power down or go to the next screen. I am currently accessing it through Siri... How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a list if things to do when the touch screen is not responsive since it could just be a software issue:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414

I would start there and then call AppleCare if a reset and restore doesn't fix the screen. It could be broken and just need to be repaired.